# Points do not exist when rasterising vector information

Tags: raster, r, terra

I am trying to create a raster from point data by rasterising it with a map of the UK given that these points reside within the UK (Given at the image below).

The dataset that I have are of weather stations scattered across the UK, and after converting them to useable coordinates from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/402473/converting-dms-to-coordinates-with-signs) I then began my intentions.

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(terra)
#load raster and reproject
rr <- rast("Over_Gb/GBOverview.tif")
rr <- project(rr, "epsg:4326", method="ngb")
#convert data frame into spat vector
sta.vec <- vect(stations, geom=c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs="epsg:4326")
#crop to extent
r <- crop(rr, sta.vec)
#rasterize
sta.ras <- sta.vec %>% terra::rasterize(r, "Stations")
```

The .tif file is downloaded from the Ordnance Survey [here](https://osdatahub.os.uk/downloads/open/GBOverviewMaps)

Wen I plot the raster image It returns an empty page, I am presuming this is because of the many NA values created during the raster conversion, so perhaps this overlaps with the points available because there are far more many than positive values?

My aim is to plot this with `add = TRUE` onto another plot so it retains its legend for the values available, and so I can add more features when plotting. So far, I can only manage by extracting the points, and plotting them as `points()`. Is there a way to plot these points as a raster? I have managed many times before, though maybe its because there are minimal values, if so how can I work around this?

plotting with points:

```
#get coordinates from cell
wind.nc <- xyFromCell(sta.ras, 1:ncell(sta.ras))
#get values from cell
val.x <- values(sta.ras)
#make into dataframe
vc.e <- data.frame(wind.nc, val.x)
re <- vc.e[complete.cases(vc.e),]
plot(r)
points(re[, 1:2])
```

It should look like this when I use:

```
plot(r)
plot(sta.ras)
```

Reproducible code of 50 stations:

```
structure(list(Stations = c("CET CENTRAL ENGLAND                     ", 
"ARMAGH                                  ", "ESKDALEMUIR                             ", 
"RADCLIFFE METEOROLOGICAL STATION OXFORD ", "HULL                                    ", 
"WICK                                    ", "LERWICK                                 ", 
"KIRKWALL                                ", "STORNOWAY AIRPORT                       ", 
"VALLEY                                  ", "WADDINGTON                              ", 
"CAMBORNE                                ", "KINLOSS                                 ", 
"CRAIBSTONE                              ", "MYLNEFIELD                              ", 
"CAMBRIDGE (B. GDNS)                     ", "ASKHAM BRYAN                            ", 
"SHAWBURY                                ", "GOUDHURST                               ", 
"PAISLEY                                 ", "RINGWAY                                 ", 
"CWMYSTWYTH                              ", "DALE FORT                               ", 
"LONG ASHTON                             ", "ALDERGROVE                              ", 
"AUCHINCRUIVE                            ", "GLENLEE                                 ", 
"THREAVE                                 ", "RONALDSWAY                              ", 
"NEWTON RIGG                             ", "GRIZEDALE                               ", 
"PRESTON: MOOR PARK                      ", "HAWARDEN BRIDGE                         ", 
"LOGGERHEADS: COLOMENDY CENTRE           ", "INVERNESS                               ", 
"ABERPORTH                               ", "GOGERDDAN                               ", 
"YEOVILTON                               ", "SWANAGE                                 ", 
"PLYMOUTH: MOUNTBATTEN                   ", "SLAPTON                                 ", 
"ST MAWGAN                               ", "BUDE                                    ", 
"BRAEMAR                                 ", "BALMORAL                                ", 
"HILLSBOROUGH                            ", "STORMONT CASTLE                         ", 
"LOUGH NAVAR FOREST                      ", "GUERNSEY: AIRPORT                       ", 
"JERSEY: AIRPORT                         "), Latitude = c("52.42000", 
"54.35000", "55.31667", "51.76111", "53.75583", "58.45000", "60.13334", 
"58.95000", "58.21361", "53.25000", "53.16611", "50.21667", "57.65000", 
"57.18000", "56.45000", "52.19305", "53.92000", "52.80000", "51.08000", 
"55.84528", "53.35000", "52.35000", "51.70000", "51.43000", "54.65000", 
"55.47694", "55.09889", "54.92500", "54.08500", "54.66972", "54.33805", 
"53.77389", "53.21667", "53.15000", "57.48695", "52.13889", "52.43195", 
"51.00611", "50.61389", "50.35389", "50.29194", "50.43694", "50.82806", 
"57.00611", "57.03695", "54.45195", "54.60305", "54.43889", "49.43306", 
"49.21695"), Longitude = c("-1.8300000", "-6.6500001", "-3.2000000", 
"-1.2638888", "-0.3563889", "-3.0833333", "-1.1833333", "-2.9000001", 
"-6.3175001", "-4.5333333", "-0.5238889", "-5.3166666", "-3.5699999", 
"-2.2000000", "-3.0699999", " 0.1319444", "-1.1700000", "-2.6700001", 
" 0.4600000", "-4.4294443", "-2.2800000", "-3.8199999", "-5.1500001", 
"-2.6700001", "-6.2199998", "-4.5661111", "-4.1861110", "-3.9500000", 
"-4.6330557", "-2.7863889", "-3.0200000", "-2.7030556", "-3.0272222", 
"-3.1961112", "-4.2230554", "-4.5719442", "-4.0200000", "-2.6400001", 
"-1.9580555", "-4.1211109", "-3.6511111", "-4.9988890", "-4.5461111", 
"-3.3969445", "-3.2200000", "-6.0700002", "-5.8288889", "-7.9030557", 
"-2.5999999", "-2.2000000")), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to simplify questions such that they do not rely on files to be downloaded; and only include code and packages that are essential to the question (do not use `library(tidyverse)` if all you use is `%>%` -- in this case it would be better not to use it , or use base-R `|>`). I know that can be challenging -- but it is a key R skill to learn as, in most cases, it will allow you to answer your own questions; and it will make this site more useful for others. I will try to do it for you:

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
s <- RGB2col(s, 1:3)
set.seed(31)
pts <- spatSample(s, 50, xy=TRUE, values=FALSE, as.points=TRUE)
plot(s)
points(pts)
```

Now if you rasterize like this

```
r <- rasterize(pts, s)
plot(r)
```

You still see some colored cells, but with the higher spatial resolution you are using it makes sense that you do not see anything. You may consider aggregating the raster first.

```
rr <- aggregate(rast(s), 10)
rr <- rasterize(pts, rr)
plot(rr)
```

Or with the image from your post:

```
x <- rast("https://i.stack.imgur.com/trH6r.png")
RGB(x) <- 1:3
set.seed(31)
pt <- spatSample(x, 50, xy=TRUE, values=FALSE, as.points=TRUE)
plot(x)
points(pt)
y <- rasterize(pt, x)
plot(y)
```

(nothing to see)

```
z <- aggregate(rast(x), c(20,10))
z <- rasterize(pt, z)
```

Now I see something.

```
plot(x)
plot(z, add=T)
```

[image]

Also, you do

```
 rr <- project(rr, "epsg:4326", method="ngb")
```

But it is generally better not to transform raster data if it can be avoided. Instead, you could use `project` to transform the points to the crs of the raster.